# Why is my custom element's pseudo-element displayed after sibling elements?

Tags: html, css

When I use this html code:

```css
box:after {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 1px 3px;
  background: blue;
  content: 'Text';
}
```

```html
<div><a href="#">Some Text #1 <box /> Some Text #2 <box /></a></div>
```

The `<box>` element is shown after "Some Text #2" instead of shown after "Some Text #1".

But when I use `<box></box>` instead of `<box />` its working good.

Is it possible to make it working but still using `<box />`. Thanks.

Comment: There is no such HTML element as `box`

Comment: And even if there were such an element, `<box />` (self-closing) means it cannot have content, and thus, also no `::before` or `::after`. **Never** leave the boundaries of 100% valid HTML.

Comment: @connexo - That's incorrect. Void (self-closing) elements can sometimes have content. See https://jsbin.com/husirazewa/1/edit?html,css,output.

Comment: @Alohci They can, by the specification, **not**. I don't care what any browser implements at any point in time; that's **unspecified behaviour**, and as such, could change at any point in time. There is no way I'd ever rely on that.

Comment: Is this part of a framework like angular or vue?

Comment: @connexo - Ah, you mean "must not", not "can not". That's a conformance requirement. You can't infer that for a hypothetical element "box". That would be reasonable if elements that had a "nothing" content model and void elements were synonymous, but the HTML5 spec explicitly says [that this is not the case](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-nothing-content-model). So it would be completely reasonable for a hypothetical "box" element to be a void element but not have a "nothing" content model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work that way, In HTML... There has to be an opening and closing tag

you cant do:
`<box/><box/><box/>` just because you want 3 boxes,

You have to do:
`<box></box><box></box><box></box>`

So the solution to your problem would be :

```
<div><a href="#">Some Text #1 <box></box>Some Text #2 <box></box></a></div>
```

I hope this helps